# How to resolve min and max date input in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I've created a function that return a substraction or an addition from current Date, and set the result in the min or max of date input :

My function :

```
  SubDate = (subDay) => {
    let tgDate = new Date();
    tgDate.setDate(tgDate.getDate() + subDay)
    return tgDate.toLocaleDateString();
  }
```

My input :

```
<input type="date" id="dateInput" min={this.SubDate(-7)} max={this.SubDate(7)} />
```

The function is working. In the navigator's inspector, I see the `min` and `max` of the input like so :

```
<input type="date" id="dateInput" min="13/09/2020" max="27/09/2020">
```

But when I try to select a date, It does'nt prevent me to choose the min date and the max date.

[image]

Can I resolve that ? Or using [DateTimePicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) instead of that.

Thank you.

Comment: For `type="date"` or any of the HTML5 date-related controls, dates must be formatted in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you ended up resolving this or not but for reference ,

```
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
<input type="date"  onChange={this.handleChange} max={today} />
```