# How to set current date as the min date on below code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I want to set the current date as the min date without giving a fixed date like the below**

```
 <input
      type="date"
      className="form-control"
      placeholder="Pick a date"
      name="closingDate" 
      min="2022-10-14"                      
      onChange={(e) => setClosingDate(e.target.value)}
       />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve min and max date input in React Js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63978960/how-to-resolve-min-and-max-date-input-in-react-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this...

```
<input
      type="date"
      className="form-control"
      placeholder="Pick a date"
      name="closingDate" 
      min={new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10)}
      onChange={(e) => setClosingDate(e.target.value)}
       />
```

Comment: Answers with explanations of code (why and how) are less often downvoted that those without...

Answer (score 2):

How about setting as current date using [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <input
      type="date"
      className="form-control"
      placeholder="Pick a date"
      name="closingDate"
      min={new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]}
      // onChange={(e) => setClosingDate(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
      type="date"
      className="form-control"
      placeholder="Pick a date"
      name="closingDate" 
      min= {new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]}                     
      onChange={(e) => setClosingDate(e.target.value)}
       />
```

As you are using react js you can assign current date to min as  above.`New Date().toISOString()` can use to find current date including time (current timestamp). Then split it and used first part of it which is the date.

Comment: This won't work sadly ...

Comment: Yeah I forgot  select first part of the date. Now it is working

Comment: lol, how's it different from mine 

Comment: @KcH Lol, how's yours different from the duplicate?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Honestly I didn't see it at all ... in fact I was going through the docs that why just `new Date()` wouldn't work ... anyways that's the people's perception ... nvm

Comment: It became same because I found date split logic from stack overflow answer . Most probably same source.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a new date object and construct a min string from that. Please enjoy this react snippet demonstrating.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
    const [ closingDate, setClosingDate ] = useState(null);

    const today = new Date();
    const year = today.getFullYear();
    const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    const day = today.getDate();
    const minStr = [year, month, day].join("-");
    
    
    return (
        <div>
          Minimum date is { today.toLocaleString() } <br />
          Closing date is { closingDate } <br />
          <input 
            type="date"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Pick a date"
            name="closingDate" 
            min={minStr}                      
            onChange={(e) => setClosingDate(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```